90s movie about substitute teacher
I remember watching a movie about 15 years ago about a white female teacher being asked to substitute in an all black/latino community school. 
The students are mostly just rude to the teacher and don't respect her but a few of them are in gangs and take a violent turn with her. 
There is also a young guy who is pretty smart but the gangs are trying to get him to join them. 
Some key plot points I can remember:

90s movie
White substitute teacher joins all black/latino community school. 
Teacher is threatened by gangs to leave the school and she refuses 
Young smart guy is pressured into joining the gang 
Young guy protects the teacher from the gang
For some reason I always thought that the young smart character was played by the actor Michael Ealy but I don't think this role is listed under his roles on Google. 

Can anyone help me identify this movie? It was pretty awesome from what I can remember 

Sounds like Freedom Writers 2007 http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0463998/

It was definitely older than 2007. At least 15 years ago.

By any chance it can be Dangerous Minds (1995)

An ex-Marine turned teacher struggles to connect with her students in an inner city school. 

Wikipedia got the full synopses of the film and student even nicknamed her "White Bread" due to her skin colour.




Good answer. Close but it's not the same movie unfortunately. I think the movie I'm referring to is slightly less mainstream so this could be a tough question. Thanks though
